# loop ajax call, to complete lenghtly operations on server

Tags: ajax, loops

I have a function, that uses ajax, that takes really long to complete.
The thing is that I have a lot of files on server, that need to be processed, and the page  I'm trying to make is like a status page.

It has a link to start processing, and file counts. It looks like this:

---

Click here to start process

files 0/500

---

When I click the link, it runs this function:

```
function generate_book_link_clicked(){
    $.getJSON("/generate_book", function(data){
      if (data['last'] == 'true'){
        $('#done').fadeIn(200);
      }else{
        $('#current_count').html(parseInt($('#current_count').text())+1);
        $('#generate_book_link').click();
     }
    });
}
```

This is the link code:

```
<a href="#" id="generate_book_link" onclick="generate_book_link_clicked">click me</a>
```

and this is the code for the counter html (the "<%= @isbn_count.to_s %>" just returns the count):

```
<span id="current_count">0</span>/<span id="total_count"><%= @isbn_count.to_s %></span>
```

But what happens is, when ajax completes, it doesn't start the process over again, but the count just starts rapidly adding without ajax calls.
It's like, the first finishes successfully, but then it just starts rapidly adding values to "current_count", and it goes like that forever even over the original count (1000/500)..

I can't figure how to start the process again, currently.

I hope I made everything clear and that someone will be able to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$('#generate_book_link').click();
```

just call your function directly:

```
generate_book_link_clicked();
```

Comment: I just tried that, and result was like this: it did the same with the unfinited loop of counter, but now it just made the same ajax calls.. I made that there are 4 jobs, but it was continued til unfinity. I checked that server returns the data['last'] == 'true' corectly.! so javascript is the problem..

Comment: The syntax of your function definition is incorrect (the parentheses are in the wrong place). Is that just a copy-paste mistake, or is it wrong in the real page?

Comment: it was a copy/paste mistake. I corrected it. So, any ideas, of whats going wrong?

Comment: Not sure what you're saying the problem is. It's supposed to make the same AJAX calls each time, isn't it?